# Is it a bad idea to apply for a job online late at night?

Tags: new-job, applications, work-time, online

I have recently applied for a job online on totaljobs.com. 
I sent a copy to my email address, and I realised that the time was 2AM when I applied!

Do you think this will frowned upon by my (possible) future employer?

Comment: I hope not, because 2 AM is usually my best time for sending out the resume :) I live in NYC, the City that never sleeps - What did they expect? :) Of course, if you were to send out resumes postmarked from the slammer, it doesn't look good on you no matter what time of the day you send them :)

Comment: Just be careful you're not making simple grammar mistakes because you're too sleepy!

Comment: @LorenzoDematté, Surely it's not a duplicate when the new question was asked over a year after this one

Comment: Yep, my bad! I have seen it after raising the flag. It's the other way aroud

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's unlikely to negatively affect your chances, or even get noticed, for that matter.

The fact that someone stayed up a bit later than the norm on one given day would be an illogical factor to include when trying to determine whether said person will make a good employee or not, as it doesn't say a whole lot regarding that, and there are a lot more important things to consider in this regard.

However, it's anyone's guess how any given employer will see it. So, if it's all the same to you, do try to avoid it.

Comment: Why are you thinking this would be a problem? I suppose an employer could say, "This guy stays up all night. He probably isn't alert when he gets to work." But he might also say, "Here's someone who stays up all night if that's what's necessary to get a task done. Bravo!" I'd guess most employers wouldn't think about it one way or the other, as they have no idea what your schedule is. Maybe you're on vacation and you're schedule got messed up. Maybe you woke up sick in the middle of the night and decided to fire off some emails before going back to bed. Maybe, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Employers are just people. I'm sure you will find someone somewhere in the world who will scorn your timing. And you will probably also find someone who will cherish it. And then you will find a vast majority who won't put thought into it.

The question is: Do you want to work for an employer who thinks less of applications submitted at night?

If you think it's unreasonable to sort applications based on e-mail timestamps, chances are this employer will have other unreasonable traits that could spawn conflict between you.

This employer would be doing you (and him) a service by rejecting your late night application.